# How to change numbers to words in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I need to insert instead of numbers divisible by 3 , "d3" word. Also instead of numbers divisible by 5 ,"d5" word. How can I do it. I have tried here:

```
puts "How many digits do u want to see?"                                              
number = gets.to_i                                                                    

number.times do |n|                                                                   
        puts "#{n}"                                                                   

        if (n % 3 == 0)                                                               
                puts "d3"                                                            
        elsif (n % 5 == 0)                                                            
                puts "d5"                                                            
        end                                                                           
end
```

If I enter number 7 the output must be :

```
1
2
d3
4
d5
d3
7
```

But I have different output when I enter number 7 :

```
How many digits do u want to see?                                                     
7                                                                                     
0                                                                                     
d3                                                                                  
1                                                                                     
2                                                                                     
3                                                                                     
d3                                                                                
4                                                                                     
5                                                                                     
d5                                                                                 
6                                                                                     
d3
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: `if (n % 3 == 0)                                                               
      puts "d3"                                                            
    elsif (n % 5 == 0)                                                            
      puts "d5" else puts "#{n}" end`

Comment: It works. Thanks but do you know how can I remove 0 because it shows me : d3 1 2 d3 4 d5 d3 . How can I remove the 1st symbol d3?

Comment: change `number.times` to `(1..number).each` use a range, also this is the fizzbuzz problem you can google for solutions

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You forget to write `2` in place of `to`.

Comment: What if the number is 15?

Comment: *Fizz Buzz* strikes again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling times on a range will throw the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `times' for 1..number:Range
```

Using times just like like in number.times will also start from 0 and end before the last number. Here is a possible solution which also adds a possibility of having a number being divisible by both 3 and 5.

```
puts "How many digits do u want to see?"
number = gets.to_i

(1..number).each do |n|
  if (n % 3 == 0 && n % 5 == 0)
    puts "..." # whatever message you like
  elsif (n % 3 == 0)
    puts "d3"
  elsif (n % 5 == 0)
    puts "d5"
  else
    puts n
  end
end
```

Comment: That's what I need. Perfect 15 now shows d3 and d5. Good job. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
puts "How many digits do u want to see?"
number = gets.to_i

(1..number).each do |n|
  if (n % 3 == 0 && n % 5 == 0)
    puts "whatever you need"
  elsif (n % 3 == 0)
    puts "d3"
  elsif (n % 5 == 0)
    puts "d5"
  else
    puts n
  end
end
```

**Changes**

1. Conditions have been updated
2. use the range `1..number` to skip 0

Comment: As a note, `puts "#{n}"` employs needless stringification. `puts n` is sufficient, `.to_s` will be called automatically.

Comment: @tadman Yes you're right, thanks for pointing it out. I've updated the answer now.

Comment: yeah if we put 15 its shows d3 but 15 is divisible by 3 and 5. . .

Comment: Yes that's right, but what exactly is the behaviour you expect when it's divisible by both? This is a basic FizzBuzz program that you are trying to do. In that we display `FizzBuzz`. but what do you expect?